# background-position won't work in Firefox/IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using background-position and it works fine in Chrome but on Firefox and IE it doesn't work as it should.

```
.badge {
background: url(badge.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 1px;
display: inline-block;
color: #9e988e;
font-size: 12px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

What shall I use to make it same in all browsers?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2rjZw/1/)

Comment: You have left center which is background-position and you background-position get rid of one or the other.

Comment: @Cam deleting left center didn't help. It still wont display the same.

Comment: This seems to work in Firefox and Chrome for me: http://cssdesk.com/KzEMC

Comment: Which version of IE are we talking about?

Comment: I'm checking on IE10/IE9 but the main issue is Firefox, it won't work there for me either (latest version). The weird thing is that when inspect it in firebug the background position isnt even there and if I add it through firebug, it works.

Comment: So you want this to be left centered, so why did you remove left-center why not remoeve background position? This question needs more info, and fiddle.

Comment: Need background position to better align the icons so text next to them is inline with image. http://jsfiddle.net/2rjZw/

Comment: @Cam Correct JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2rjZw/1/

Comment: Your fiddle looks right

Comment: @Cam Yeah but this doesn't work in Firefox/IE as it does in Chrome.

Comment: I looked at it in FF, IE and chrome. Everything works fine.

Comment: @user3187469 You _really_ should start telling us what the difference is now.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer does this with `background-position-x` or `background-position-y`. Firefox doesn’t support that..

Comment: You could write `background-position: 0px 1px; background-position-x: 0px; background-position-y: 1px;`

Answer (score 0):

just came across a similar issue today.

This can get a little weird, but try adding this to your style.

Example
`background-position-x: 54%;
background-position-y: 10%;`

You may have to mess around with the exact position, but most browsers accept it.

Comment: this isn't supported by Firefox